# Syntax error in the JOIN operation

Tags: sql, vb.net, join, ms-access-2010, oledb

I have a search button which searches in 4 tables. So I made the Sql query with three inner, and I have CheckBoxes so if the CheckBox is checked it adds the conditions to the query. But I have a problem which is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>   Syntax error in the JOIN operation

```
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Sql, myConnection)
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim sql = "SELECT * from (tblDopages AS A INNER JOIN tblMatrice AS B on A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice) INNER JOIN (tblRefMatrice AS C on B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) INNER JOIN (tblRefMatDetails AS D on C.intIDref = D.intIDRef) WHERE "

    If CKBrefech.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "strRefEch = '" & TBrefech.Text & "'  AND "
    End If
    If CKBmethode.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "strMethode = '" & CBmethode.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBpurif.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "strPurif = '" & CBpurif.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBmatrice.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "strMatrice = '" & CBmatrice.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBmol.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "strMolecule = '" & CBmol.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBechprep.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "datDatePrepa >= @DatPrepa AND "
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DatPrepa", OleDbType.Date).Value = DTPechprep.Value.Date
    End If
    If CKBechau.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "datDatePrepa <= @Datau AND "
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Datau", OleDbType.Date).Value = DTPechau.Value.Date
    End If
    If CKBtrigprepa.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "strTrigPrepa = '" & TBtrigprepa.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBtriganaly.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "strTrigAnaly = '" & TBtrigAnaly.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBappar.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "strNomTech = '" & CBappar.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBnumappar.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "[strEquip(Appareil)] = '" & CBnumappar.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If CKBteneurmini.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "dblDopage >= " & TBteneurmini.Text & " AND "
    End If
    If CKBteneurmax.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "dblDopage <= " & TBteneurmax.Text & " AND "
    End If

    If GroupBox1.Enabled Then
        Try
            If CKBnomref.Checked Then
                sql = sql & "D.strReferentiel = '" & CBnomref.Text & "' AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv1.Checked Then
                sql = sql & "D.strNIveau1 = '" & CBniv1.Text & "' AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv2.Checked Then
                sql = sql & "D.strNiveau2 = '" & CBniv2.Text & "' AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv3.Checked Then
                sql = sql & "D.strNiveau3 = '" & CBniv3.Text & "' AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv4.Checked Then
                sql = sql & "D.strNiveau4 = '" & CBniv4.Text & "' AND "
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
    If sql.EndsWith(" AND ") Then
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 4)
    End If
    ' Remove the WHERE if no textbox has been filled....'
    If sql.EndsWith(" WHERE ") Then
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 7)
    End If

    ' cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.Connection = myConnection
    Dim MyDataSet As New DataSet
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myConnection)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DatPrepa", DTPechprep.Value))  'adding date parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@datau", DTPechprep.Value))     'adding date parameters to datatable
    'da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Matrice", matrice.ToString))     'adding Matrice parameters to datatable

    da.Fill(MyDataSet, "Matrice")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables("Matrice")

    'to focus on first row of DGV after populating it 
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True

    LBnumresult.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
```

Comment: try removing the `[`  in the query and check .

Comment: I've already tried to remove the [ but still the same problem, but i think that i should place Parenthesis ()  for each inner join do you have any idea ?Thank you for your reply

Comment: You have IS instead of ON with some of your joins.

Comment: the sytnax for your joins in general looks odd to me

Comment: Can't you look at sql variable in debug mode before executing??

Comment: I didn't get it IS instead of ON and btw the problem was solved by adding Parenthesis (you can review the new sql query) now the problem is Syntax error in the JOIN operation any idea thank you anyway

Comment: Yes but i'm not an expert in debugging mode @GiorgiNakeuri how can i know what is causing the error ?

Comment: @Marwan, add a breakpoint to line `cmd.CommandText = sql`. Run program, when breakpoint hits mouse over the variable sql and copy its value to your question so we see actual sql statement that is generated.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean when you say " 
I didn't get it IS instead of ON "

Comment: "SELECT * from (tblDopages AS A INNER JOIN tblMatrice AS B on A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice) INNER JOIN (tblRefMatrice AS C on B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) INNER JOIN (tblRefMatDetails AS D on C.intIDref = D.intIDRef) WHERE strMethode = 'MarMeth1' AND strPurif = 'MarPurif2' "

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri you've got it man !

Comment: @Takarii that means i didn't understand your comment : You have IS instead of ON with some of your joins

Comment: some of your joins were using IS where ON should have been (you corrected this in one of your revisions eg. `INNER JOIN AS tblRefMatDetails D is [C.intIDref ] = [` from your original edit IS should have been on. (this is what i meant :) )

Comment: Aha don't know cause i didn't see any IS, anyway do have any suggestion for this error ? @Takarii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have some syntax errors. Change this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (tblDopages AS A 
INNER JOIN tblMatrice AS B ON A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice) 
INNER JOIN (tblRefMatrice AS C ON B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) 
INNER JOIN (tblRefMatDetails AS D ON C.intIDref = D.intIDRef) 
WHERE strMethode = 'MarMeth1' AND strPurif = 'MarPurif2'
```

to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ((tblDopages AS A 
INNER JOIN tblMatrice AS B ON A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice) 
INNER JOIN tblRefMatrice AS C ON B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) 
INNER JOIN tblRefMatDetails AS D ON C.intIDref = D.intIDRef
WHERE strMethode = 'MarMeth1' AND strPurif = 'MarPurif2'
```

General:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ((--here N-2 parentesis
     table1
JOIN table2 ON ...)
JOIN table3 ON ...)
JOIN table4 ON ...)
JOIN tableN ON ...--here no parentesis
```

Comment: I tried to make left join to display all the results from my main table tblDopage but the program crashed after making the changes? Can you please help me . This is the sql query :

Comment: Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM ((tblDopages AS A Left JOIN tblMatrice AS B ON A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice) INNER JOIN tblRefMatrice AS C ON B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) INNER JOIN tblRefMatDetails AS D ON C.intIDref = D.intIDRef where "                                                                     The error is :unsupported  JOIN Expression                                                     Thank you in advance

Comment: @Marwan, after first `left join` try to change following `inner joins` to `left joins` and use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I used which contains 2 inner join between 3 tables and left join.
I made first the inner join and finally the left join

Dim sql = "SELECT distinct A.* FROM  ((tblMatrice AS B INNER JOIN tblRefMatrice AS C ON B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) INNER JOIN tblRefMatDetails AS D ON C.intIDref = D.intIDRef) LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDopages AS A on A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice where "